# Parse unicode in string using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to **filter** a string from a `onmousemove` event (tooltip).
The filtered string needs to be showed as text.

**The problem** is that the string looks like:
*This string needs to be filtered. \r\n There is also unicode in this string \u00EB.*

**What I want:**
*This string needs to be filtered.* 
*There is also unicode in this string: ë*

The **HTML** looks as follows:

```
<img onmousemove="showInfo(event,'This string needs to be filtered. \r\n There is also unicode in this string: \u00EB.');" onmouseout="hideInfo();" />
```

This is what I **tried**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td > img').each(function() {
        var toolTip = $(this).attr('onmousemove'),
            comment = toolTip.match(/([\'])(\\?.)*?\1/),
            parentCell = $(this).parent();

        $("div.timelineRow").css("padding", "7px");
        $("<td><b>Info:</b><span> " + comment[0] + "</span></td>").insertAfter(parentCell);
        $(this).insertAfter(parentCell);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the "showInfo" function in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decoding your Unicode character using JSON.parse. (Note the wrapping in double quotes to make it valid JSON).

Then replace the new lines with `<br>` tags to convert them into HTML line break elements (The browser won't render `\r\n`).

e.g.

```
var htmlComment = JSON.parse('"' + comment[0] + '"').replace("\r\n", "<br>");
$("<td><b>Info:</b><span> " + htmlComment + "</span></td>").insertAfter(parentCell);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that if the only reason you're doing this is for display purposes, there is a CSS property [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) that may be all you need to use. For example: [https://jsfiddle.net/abcyymee/](https://jsfiddle.net/abcyymee/)